# Is there any way to draw a "streak" (fading "digital phosphor" effect) on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a moving dot on an HTML5 canvas that follows a complicated trajectory. This I know how to do; see, for example, the [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) as implemented below. But with small dots it is hard to follow. **Is there a way to add a blurry trail behind a dot?** I can keep past history of drawn points, I just don't know how to make them fade.

In technical terms, I suppose this would be a polyline/curve where the opacity/width/color changes smoothly along the curve. I know how to draw polylines (and can figure out the Bezier curve stuff if I need to), but I don't know how to apply a smooth gradient along a path.

(Digital oscilloscopes solved this "problem" by having a Digital Phosphor Oscilloscope effect where the scope emulated the old analog "phosphor" effect: areas hit by the scope's "beam" would take a while to fade.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 var x = 1, y = 0, z = 0, t=0;
 function onTick(timestamp)
 {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  var cx = 150;
  var cy = 150;
  var r = 5;
  var now = timestamp * 0.001;
  var dt = now - t;
  t = now;
  if (dt > 0.1)
   dt = 0.1;
  // Lorenz attractor
  var sigma = 10, rho=28, beta=8/3;
  var dxdt = sigma*(y-x);
  var dydt = x*(rho-z)-y;
  var dzdt = x*y-beta*z;
  x += dt*dxdt;
  y += dt*dydt;
  z += dt*dzdt;
  
  var drawx = cx + r*x;
  var drawy = cy + r*y;
  var rdot = 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(drawx, drawy, rdot, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(onTick);  
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(onTick);
  });
</script></head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the technique I would use is to keep an array of all past positions, and then use that array as the means for plotting and drawing the dots to the canvas, this way, you have full control over the opacity of each dot (the "leading" dot is the darkest, while all the "follower" dots get more and more transparent the further down the line you go...

Comment: Please don't add tags willy-nilly without reading the question. The "drawing streak" trick really has nothing to do with animation as it could be shown statically.

Comment: @radiovisual yeah I had something like that in mind... the problem (which I will restate in my question) is that I don't know how to draw a polyline / curve that has a gradient of color/opacity/width along the curve.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of clearing the rectangle each frame, just paint it in an alpha channel to save those previous dots momentarily.  I replaced your `clearRect` with `fillRect` the `fillStyle` is white see-through.

Keep in ming you can adjust the alpha channel, this will make the dot stay for longer/short duration.  In my code this is the `0.04` in the `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04)";`.  I just adjusted it lower to make those traces stay for a longer time.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 var x = 1, y = 0, z = 0, t=0;
 function onTick(timestamp)
 {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  var cx = 150;
  var cy = 150;
  var r = 5;
  var now = timestamp * 0.001;
  var dt = now - t;
  t = now;
  if (dt > 0.1)
   dt = 0.1;
  // Lorenz attractor
  var sigma = 10, rho=28, beta=8/3;
  var dxdt = sigma*(y-x);
  var dydt = x*(rho-z)-y;
  var dzdt = x*y-beta*z;
  x += dt*dxdt;
  y += dt*dydt;
  z += dt*dzdt;
  
  var drawx = cx + r*x;
  var drawy = cy + r*y;
  var rdot = 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(drawx, drawy, rdot, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(onTick);  
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(onTick);
  });
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: oh -- that's creative!

Comment: @JasonS I was re-reading the question, and in the link you put there you can see the light lines, almost like a track for the dot to follow.  Do you need it like that, or will this fade effect work?  You can adjust the alpha channel to make the dot stay longer/shorter duration.

Comment: Nah, that's an independent effect; I know how to draw those sorts of things, and I'm guessing what you'd need to do would be to have two canvas elements, one that is "permanent" and one that has the fading alpha effect like you've described. I think what I would probably do in practice is instead of a single dot, I would draw a line/curve between the last two points, and then apply the fade effect like you've done.

Comment: Yeah i was just trying something out but didn't quite get it

Comment: @JasonS yes just need to turn up the alpha, i thought is was kind of cool how the dots stay forever, but if you turn up the alpha from .04 to .15 or above the dots should completely disappear for sure.  I was playing around trying to get the "track" to stay visible underneath but didn't quite get it: https://jsfiddle.net/nLj78zpd/

Answer (score 0):

Classic trick was to draw a polyline instead single dot, altering color and/or opacity per each vertice of polyline, the brightest would be the furthest along traectory

Comment: ummm... well, yeah, I know *what* I want to see (basically what you're saying), but I have no idea *how* to do that.